# manage new scheduled job

Tags: cron-job, cron, scheduled-job

What should I put on this screen to make the cron work for mailing? 
I use wordpress 4.9.6  Thanks

[image]

Comment: Can you check your Admin > System Status and report back on what it is saying about your 'cron'.

Comment: And how can I do this? I did not understand, Thanks petednz

Comment: This link on your site will tell you your 'system status' including whether cron is running or not - /civicrm/a/#/status

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean the job that is used to *send Scheduled Mailings* . You do not have to create it. It is part of the standard configuration. So the only thing to do is to enable it. But to be complete here is the configuration:
[image]

Comment: Thanks Kainuk, and this serves to put the cron in action?

Comment: The answer is for the mailing part. Information to put the cron in action you can find at https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/jobs/ .